# Jquery toggle text on click

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to solve this, i succeeded somewhat but i'm stuck now.

I have this structure:

```
<h4>title</h4>
<p>text</p>
<hr />
<h4>title</h4>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<hr />
<h4>title</h4>
<p>text</p>
<hr />
```

What i'm basically trying to accomplish is to toggle the words tonen (meaning open) and verbergen (meaning hide) when slidding the P's up and down. At the moment i append a span with the word tonen and check wether its shown or not.

The content is hidden on load, tonen is shown, but when h4 is clicked, the content is shown but tonen won't change to verbergen. I have read about live and on but don't get it.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
    $("h4").append("<span> - tonen</span>");
    $("h4").nextUntil("hr").hide();
    $("h4").click(function () {
        $(this).nextUntil("hr").slideToggle("fast");
        if(span.text() == " - tonen"){
            span.text(" - verbergen");
        } else {
            span.text(" - tonen");
        }
    });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to get text of your current child `span` of clicked `h4` and change to opposite text based on retrieved span's text:

```
$("h4").click(function () {
    $(this).nextUntil("hr").slideToggle("fast");
    var text = $(this).find('span').text();
    $(this).find('span').text(text == " - verbergen " ? " - tonen " : " - verbergen ");
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/P2hXS/3/)

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO 1](http://jsbin.com/azazub/2/edit)**</kbd>

```
$("h4").append(" - <span>tonen</span>").click(function() {
    var $sp = $('span', this);
    $(this).nextUntil("hr").slideToggle("fast");
    $sp.text( $sp.text()=="tonen"?"verbergen":"tonen");
}).nextUntil("hr").hide();
```

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO 2](http://jsbin.com/azazub/3/edit)**</kbd>

```
$("h4").append(" - <span>tonen</span><span style='display:none;'>verbergen</span>").click(function() {
     $(this).nextUntil("hr").slideToggle(400).end().find('span').toggle();
}).nextUntil("hr").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you ever declared your span variable. You need to select the element you'll be manipulating and then it should work:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("h4").append("<span> - tonen</span>");
        $("h4").nextUntil("hr").hide();
        $("h4").click(function () {
            $(this).nextUntil("hr").slideToggle("fast");
            var $span = $(this).find('span');
            if($span.text() == " - tonen"){
               $span.text(" - verbergen");
            } else {
               $span.text(" - tonen");
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PTXX8/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short script that shows the first paragraph but hides all others unless 'more...' is clicked. It even creates the 'more...' button. All you need to do to use this is wrap the text block (which contains a number of paragraphs) between ... and initiate the script:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".teaser p").eq(0).attr("class","clsTea");
    $(".teaser").after("<span class='moreTea'>more...</span>");
    $(".clsTea").siblings().css("background-color","yellow").hide();
    $(".moreTea").click(
    function(){
        var clktxt = $(".moreTea").text();
        $(".clsTea").siblings().toggle(1000,function(){
            if (clktxt=='more...'){
                $(".moreTea").text('less...');
            } else {
                $(".moreTea").text('more...');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I hope that this helps